# Разряды прилагательных

Tags: прилагательные

По какому признаку я могу найти среди них  притяжательное прилагательное? Я думаю,что правильный вариант третий. Потому,что там можно задать вопрос чей? Но я не уверена

- отцовский взгляд
- студенческий взгляд
- помещичий дом
- партизанский штаб
- директорский кабинет

Comment: Понятно. Я думаю,что это вариант третий .Потому ,что там можно задать вопрос чей? Но я не уверена. Можете помочь, каким путем  могу отличать притяжательные прилагательные

Comment: Суффикс -ск- - это не суффикс притяжательных прилагательных. А вот -ий в слове "помещичий"- вполне!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли

Answer (score 3):

Определить разряд прилагательного не так просто, как иногда представляется.  В общем случае выбор делается  **не только по суффиксу,** нужно учитывать и другие признаки – лексические  и грамматические особенности конкретного прилагательного,  а также сочетание, в котором оно применяется (в задании приведены именно сочетания, а не отдельные слова), а иногда и контекст. В  примерах использованы следующие суффиксы прилагательных: СК, ОВСК, ЕСК, ИЙ.

**(1) Помещичий дом**

Суффикс ИЙ выделяется среди остальных, поэтому кажется, что притяжательным является именно прилагательное «помещичий»  в сочетании «помещичий дом». Однако «помещичий»  имеет два значения: принадлежащий помещику и свойственный помещику. К сожалению, сочетание тоже не проясняет ситуацию: речь может идти о доме, принадлежащем конкретному помещику (притяжательное значение), или об особенностях устройства любого помещичьего дома (относительное значение).

**(2) Отцовский взгляд**

Суффикс ОВСК может иметь **притяжательное** значение (отцовский дом), но может быть относительным или даже качественным  (отцовские чувства вообще или особая психологическая привязанность к ребенку).

«Отцовский взгляд» –  это **притяжательное** значение (его взгляд), если речь идет о принадлежности конкретному человеку  ВЗГЛЯД, 1. Направленность глаз на кого-, что-л.; взор.  2. Мнение, суждение, оценка кого-, чего-л.

А  в сочетании «типичный отцовский взгляд» принадлежность утрачивается.

**(3)  Студенческий взгляд**

Суффикс СК относительный, но в данном сочетании он, вероятно,  развивает качественное значение – имеющий характерные особенности для этой группы людей.

**(4) партизанский штаб, директорский кабинет**

Суффикс СК в этих примерах относительный, он обозначает **предназначенность** для группы лиц или для лица, выполняющего какую-то должность (директора в данном случае).

**ВЫВОД.** Итак, в данном примере два возможных варианта: ***помещичий дом и отцовский взгляд.*** Для окончательного выбора необходим **контекст.**

Answer (score 1):

Притяжательные прилагательные обозначают принадлежность предмета лицу или животному и отвечают на вопросы чей? чья? чьё? чьи? Образуются при помощи суффиксов –ин, –ов, –ев, –ск– (–ий).

В вашем случае не хватает контекста. Если исходить из представленных фраз, прямо по правилу, то получится, что все фразы соответствуют.

Взгляд - чей? - отцовский. Притяжательное прилагательное.

Студенческий взгляд - чей? - студента. Притяжательное прилагательное.

Помещичий дом - чей? - помещика. Притяжательное прилагательное.

Партизанский штаб - чей? - партизана. Притяжательное прилагательное.

Директорский кабинет - чей? директора. Притяжательное прилагательное.